# bash - get 1st argument of current command I am editing via history, or similar?

Tags: bash, history-expansion

Often I'm writing a command in a bash prompt, where I want to get previous arguments, in the CURRENT line I'm typing out, and put in other places in the command.

A simple example, would be if I want to rename a file. I would

- type out the `mv` command
- type the filename I want to move, `~/myTestFileWithLongFilename.txt`
- now I want to just change the extension of the file that I supplied in the first argument, without typing it again.

Can I use history or bash completion in some way to autocomplete that first argument?

```
$ mv ~/myTestFileWithLongFilename.txt ~/myTestFileWithLongFilename.md
```

I know of course I could execute the incomplete command, to get it into the history, and then reference it with `!$`, but then my history is polluted with invalid commands, and I'm wondering if there's a better way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible but a bit cumbersome. In bash `!#` refers to the entire
line already typed. You can specify a given word you want to refer to
after `:`, in this case it would be `!#:1`. You can expand it in place
using `shell-expand-line` built-in readline keybinding
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>.

Comment: I get "-bash: :1: bad word specifier" error

Comment: looks like # is excessive, i.e. !:1 and alt+ctrl+e works just fine

Answer (score 10):

To lessen the amount of typing needed for that `mv` command, a brace expansion could be used:

```bsh
mv ~/myTestFileWithLongFilename.{txt,md}
```

The brace expansion expands to `~/myTestFileWithLongFilename.txt` followed by `~/myTestFileWithLongFilename.md` (it's important to get the `{txt,md}` order right).

Brace expansion work in `bash` regardless of whether you type them on the command line or in a script.

A brace expansion, `prefix{word1,word2,word3}suffix`, would repeat the `prefix` and `suffix` string for each `wordN` in the actual brace, generating the three separate words `prefixword1suffix`, `prefixword2suffix`, and `prefixword3suffix`.  You may also use ranges, such as `{1..4}` or `{p..u}` in brace expansions.

Comment: Thanks - didnt quite get that's how that could work... nice - but what if the argument I wanted to have it show up in was the 5th argument, for example? (ie not a `mv` command, but something else)

Comment: @BradParks I only covered the command that you actually showed. If you can show a command in which you have to repeat the fifth argument with some modification, then maybe I could give you some example of that too.  The nice thing about the brace expansion that I showed is that it works in scripts as well (since it doesn't rely on history expansions).

Comment: agreed - it's definitely a short and concise way of doing what I do about 75% of the time, so that's great!

Answer (score 2):

Interactively, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> then  <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (period).

Repeat <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to go farther back in your command history, extracting token #1 from commands before the most recent.  (The command itself is token #0,  <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)

Without the alt-`<token-number>` modifier, alt-`.` takes the *last* arg of the previous command.  e.g. `mkdir foo` / `cd`  alt+.  return to make a directory and CD into it.

Normally for anything other than the last token (one modified keystroke) I'd just up-arrow, control-w or alt+d then control-y to kill the word and yank it back to not mess up my history, then down-arrow and control-y to yank it again where I want it in the command line I'm editing.  This is in bash, BTW.

Comment: This is very cool :-) unfortunately for me, my GUI terminal emulator steals Alt+1. I suspect some other people will be in the same situation.

Comment: @DavidZ: So does mine; I used `esc-1` to test this.  But that makes it even slower to use, even when you do remember how the indexing works and can mentally count faster than you can up-arrow and move the cursor around with ctrl-left or ctrl-right to go by words.  Like I said, I generally only use unmodified alt-`.` which Konsole passes through just fine, and up-arrow / kill/yank to copy/paste for other things that aren't at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

With `set -o vi`, press escape, `byw$p` (you may need to add spaces or such, and you may need `B` or `W`). Then you just have to touch things up.

Comment: good idea - i use vim style inputs in bash, and never thought of doing it that way... nice!